What does C++ _Unfancy do?
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and C++
In some code I see _Unfancy(...); and also _Unfancy(_Allocate_at_least_helper(...));
Visual studio documentation can not help me on _Unfancy, can't find anything on this subject.
'The C++ programing language, 4th ed, C++11' does not mention it.
Search in cplusplus.com does not provide me with some explanation or documentation.
Hits in google on _Unfancy are not many and all what I see is indirect.
Are _Unfancy(...) and _Allocate_at_least_helper(...) microsoft specific calls? Is there any documentation on what it is suppose to do and how/when to use it?
Kind regards.
Addition after the reply from @heap underrun:
Yes, I'm browsing in microsoft headers. And microsoft is kind enough to stick to the rules and use an '_' but not kind enough to tell what it is doing. Fortunately in my configuration and for the use that I'm looking at it is relative simple. I was curious about the calls but I think that the reply by @heap underrun clarifies the lack of documentation (and also that these kind of calls are not portable).

Since identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for internal use by the standard library / compiler, I assume you encountered those in Microsoft's header files. Those are internal implementation details and should not be used by other programmers.

It is an implementation detail. User defined allocators are allowed to use "fancy pointers" that are not ordinary pointers, but perhaps a class type. _Unfancy is trying to get the "real" pointer (memory address) out of that, when needed.

Fancy pointers are a rarely used abstraction in the Allocator abstraction of the standard library. Fancy pointers allow an allocator to replace pointer types that would normally be used (e.g. as the result of an allocation) by other types that still, to some degree, behave similar to actual pointer types. Any allocator-aware standard library type will also support such fancy pointers and _Unfancy will be part of implementing that support.

Hint: avoid to consult cplusplus, since it sometimes contains inaccuracies and errors, and prefer cppreference instead.

May be related code: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/xmemory
